# Is there any option to make my curves more smooth?

Tags: scilab, xcos

I used Scilab to get this output. Is there any option in Xcos simulation parameters to make my curves more smooth?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r32Ke.png  [Scilab's figure][1]

Answer (score 0):

This may not be of much help, but it, as a whole, depends on the time interval you are choosing. Is there a way to change the time scale? Maybe put 1E-5 instead of 0E0. I suspect that writing 0 is making the program choose a default time scale.

Comment: Thanks, @franjefriten. Changing the time scale does not change anything, but I could solve it by changing the clock period size.